# Why is the smallest ID in last?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT * 
FROM CSDMSSJ.dbo.EOBImage WITH (NOLOCK)  
WHERE EOBArchiveID = 32223
```

[image: tbl]

Comment: No reason to expect it to be last all the time. You would need an order by clause to guarantee the results to be sorted

Answer (score 1):

use `order by ID` in ascending to achieve this

```
 SELECT * 
    FROM CSDMSSJ.dbo.EOBImage 
    WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE EOBArchiveID = 32223 
    order by ID asc
```

Comment: asc is optional. So order by ID should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

From the look of your table structure, you can either:

1. Include ID column as the table primary key

   - this will physically sort the data so everytime you query, the data is already sorted
   - Joins and search based on this column will be much faster
2. Include 'Order By' clause as explained by others

Comment: Creation of PRIMARY_KEY with CLUSTERED_INDEX will only sort data PHYSICALLY. Other type could be NON-CLUSTERED, which won't make data in order physically.